# boxsizers not displaying correctly WX.PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets, wxpython

So my approach here is to have a wx.notebook that's displays my 25 images per tab. I was trying to put my images along with a tittle in independent box Sizers and then place 5 of those independent ones in a horizontal box sizers(theres 5 horizontal sizers per tab.).So each horizontal one takes 5 vertical sizers (5*5 = 25). im then placing these 5 horizontal sizers in one vertical sizer so that I get the 5X5 grid look. It loads correctly and I know the images are stored correctly but when I display them it only shows one of the images per row. I don't know what im doing wrong. Here is the code

```
    listOfSizers = []
    listofHSizers = []
    listofVsizers = []

    bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
    bSizer14 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
    self.waferTab = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition,size = wx.Size( 900,1000 ) , style = wx.NB_TOP)

    for i in range(waferNum):
        temp = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        listOfSizers.append(temp)
    for i in range(numOfTabs*5):
        temp = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        listofHSizers.append(temp) 
    for i in range(numOfTabs):
        temp = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        listofVsizers.append(temp)


    for tab in range(numOfTabs):

            tempPanel = wx.Panel(self.waferTab,wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

            listOfPanels.append(tempPanel)

    waferDesign = WaferInfo(die_size = (.2,.35),center_xy= (10 ,6.5), dia= 4.3 , edge_excl= 0.0 )

    for i in range(waferNum):
        temp = wm_core.WaferMapPanel(listOfPanels[i//25], xydList[i], waferDesign, data_type='discrete'.lower() , show_die_gridlines= False )
        boxText = wx.StaticText( listOfPanels[i//25], wx.ID_ANY, mapTitles[i][0], wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        boxText.Wrap(-1)
        listOfSizers[i].Add(boxText, 0 , wx.ALIGN_CENTER , 5)
        listOfSizers[i].Add(temp, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

    currentHSizer = 0 
    nextHSizer = 0 
    currentSizer = 0 
    nextSizer = 0

    for i in range(waferNum ):
        if(nextHSizer != 4):
            listofHSizers[currentHSizer].Add(listOfSizers[i], 0 , wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 3)
            nextHSizer +=1
        elif(nextHSizer == 4):
            listofHSizers[currentHSizer].Add(listOfSizers[i], 0 , wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 3)
            currentHSizer += 1
            nextHSizer = 0


    for i in range(len(listofHSizers)):
        if(nextSizer !=4):
            listofVsizers[currentSizer].Add(listofHSizers[i],0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT,5)
            nextSizer +=1
        elif(nextSizer == 4):
            listofVsizers[currentSizer].Add(listofHSizers[i],0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
            currentSizer +=1
            nextSizer = 0
    print(len(listOfSizers))
    print(len(listofHSizers))
    print(len(listofVsizers))

    for tab in range(numOfTabs):
        tabString = ("Page"+ str(self.tabNumber))    
        listOfPanels[tab].SetSizer(listofVsizers[tab])
        listOfPanels[tab].Layout()
        listofVsizers[tab].Fit( listOfPanels[tab] )
        self.waferTab.AddPage(listOfPanels[tab], tabString, select=False)
        self.tabNumber += 1

    bSizer6.Add(self.waferTab ,1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5)
    bSizer6.Add( bSizer14, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
    self.SetSizer(bSizer6 )
    self.Layout()
    #self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
```

and the output looks like this 
[image]

each row its suppose to have 5 but it only has one. Any idea on why this could be would be helpful. Also I do know I could use a grid to make it easier but im not allowed to use a grid due to restrictions.

Comment: how big is the image? i.e. if you open it in the paintbrush/gimp what size is reported? Also, the layout is processed just like the XML. So if you need somethingand something to be added you should do it like: `horSizer1->Add( panel ); mainSizer->Add( horSizer );` and you code is a little hard to follow.

Comment: as an example - why do you need to store the sizers in the array? Are you planning to show/hide them? And finally, why you can't use grid sizers?

Comment: you should also consider using RAD tool - something like wxGlade which can generate Python code for you.

Comment: I use wx.formbuilder and it displays fine on the tool but not the actual script the size is not the issue for sure and the sizers its just so I know what tittle to assign to each of these drawnings . I think it may have to do with the way im displaying them. wx.expand

Comment: Just curious: what possible kind of restrictions could conceivably prevent you from using `wxGridSizer` or `wxFlexGridSizer` while allowing you to use `wxBoxSizer`?

Answer (score 0):

You set the **proportion parameter** (second at wxSizer.Add(..., p, ...)) as `0` for all items. So, there's no layout, all items go to the same place, center, due to `wx.ALIGN_CENTER` flag.

Setting a proportion = 1 value for all sub-sizers of a sizer makes the allocated space to be evenly distributed among the sub-sizers. Different proportions share the space for each sub-sizer proportional to its proportion.

Also, `listOfPanels[tab].SetSizer(listofVsizers[tab])` set a vertical sizer for each page. The `tab` index is in [0, numOfTabs-1] range. Thus, you need to reset `currentSizer` before filling `listofVsizers`.

Or... you want (why?) to have all main sizers in an array. Then the size of the array is 5*numOfTabs (not just numOfTabs). This means you must adjust the index instead of just `tab`, and then don't reset `currentSizer`.

You see, there's some confusing code. You should use a debugger to see the values of the indices you use.